# Is there any caveats in sending response before resolving promises in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there any caveats in sending response before resolving promises in express?

For instance, is it OK to do this:

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {  ​
 ​res.send('Response sent before other stuff!');

 ​await something();
 await somethingElse();
});
```

Will I have some hard-to-debug bugs?

Comment: Are you sending more data after waiting for the promises to settle?

Comment: *"Will I have some hard-to-debug bugs?"* With the code above, regardless of whether you await those promises before or after sending, you will have unhandled rejections if anything goes wrong. Don't pass `async` functions to things that won't use the promise they return (`app.get` won't), or if you do, make sure that **all** of the code in the function is wrapped with `try`/`catch` so you can handle errors locally. Nothing in `app.get` is going to handle your `async` function returning a promise that eventually rejects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're not sending more data later. If that's the case, I'd probably call `end` to let Express know the response is complete, but I don't think Express cares what your function does after that. Express doesn't expect the lifetime of the call to the function and the lifetime of building the response to match (they almost never do, usually the function just starts a process and the response is filled in by callbacks).

Aside from that, though, if you're going to pass an `async` function into `app.get` (or anything else that doesn't handle the promise `async` functions return), be sure to wrap all of your code in a `try`/`catch` and handle the errors, since the thing you're returning the promise to won't handle promise rejections.

So for instance:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {  
    // Part 1: The code that handles producing the response
    try {
        // ...presumably some code here that may fail...
        res.send('Response sent before other stuff!').end();
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
    } catch (e) {
        // ...send appropriate error response...
        // Return so the other code doesn't run
        return;
    }

    // Part 2: The code after the response
    try {
        await something();
        await somethingElse();
    } catch (e) {
        // ...handle and/or log the error, etc...
    }
});
```

Note the two different blocks there, one for errors that may affect the response, one for errors that don't.

(You'd probably want to abstract this pattern into a function rather than rewriting it every time.)